# How do I solve Handle_Error canon EDSDK Error 97/61?

Tags: c++, edsdk, canon-sdk

So I am trying to download the latest picture I took, but I keep getting error code 97, which is 61 in hex. I looked it up in the EDSDKErrors.h and it seems to be a handle error. I don't know how to resolve this error so all the help and suggestions are welcome :).

```
const EdsChar *fileName = "Photos/Testt.jpg";
void download_img(EdsDirectoryItemRef object)
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    EdsStreamRef stream = NULL;
    EdsDirectoryItemInfo dirItemInfo;
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        err = EdsCreateFileStream(fileName, kEdsFileCreateDisposition_CreateAlways, kEdsAccess_ReadWrite, &stream);
    }

    // Download image
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "download started" << std::endl;
        err = EdsDownload(object, dirItemInfo.size, stream);
    }
    std::cout << std::hex << err << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds (5));
    // Issue notification that download is complete
    if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "download complete" << std::endl;
        err = EdsDownloadComplete(object);
    }

    // Release stream
    if (stream != NULL)
    {
        EdsRelease(stream);
        stream = NULL;
    }
}


EdsError EDSCALLBACK handleObjectEvent(EdsObjectEvent event, EdsBaseRef object, EdsVoid * context)
{
    download_img(object);
    return EDS_ERR_OK;
}

void init_camera(EdsCameraRef & camera)
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    EdsCameraListRef cameraList = NULL;
    EdsUInt32 count = 0;
    camera = NULL;

    err = EdsInitializeSDK();
    err = EdsGetCameraList(&cameraList);
    err = EdsGetChildCount(cameraList, &count);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        err = EdsGetChildAtIndex(cameraList, 0, &camera);
        EdsRelease(cameraList);
    }
    EdsSetObjectEventHandler(camera, kEdsObjectEvent_DirItemCreated, handleObjectEvent, NULL);
    EdsSendStatusCommand(camera, kEdsCameraStatusCommand_UIUnLock, 0);
    EdsSendStatusCommand(camera, kEdsCameraStatusCommand_EnterDirectTransfer, 0);
}

void take_photo(EdsCameraRef camera, int count, int interv_millsec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        EdsOpenSession(camera);
        EdsSendCommand(camera, kEdsCameraCommand_TakePicture, 0);
        download_img(camera);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interv_millsec));
        EdsCloseSession(camera);
    }
}
```

and this is my main:

```
int main (){
    EdsCameraRef camera;
    std::cout <<"initialized" << std::endl;
    init_camera(camera);
    take_photo(camera, 1,100);
    std::cout <<"pic made" << std::endl;
    dispose(camera);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to add delays and change the inDiItemRef, but nothing seems to work like I want it to. The furthest I got was to download the second latest picture, which is not what I want.

Comment: I am not familiar with the canon-sdk, but looking at your code, you fail to stop your program if you encounter an error.  For example: `if (err == EDS_ERR_OK)` -- what if `err != EDS_ERR_OK`?  Your program continues as if nothing is wrong (and no, just printing the code out doesn't stop the processing).  Shouldn't you inspect right there what the error is and abort (or return) from the function?